# RazorPages with filenames that include a hyphen cause IntelliSense to break

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

When using RazorPages￼ with filenames that include a hyphen, it causes Visual Studio's tooling to show a red squiggly line on valid code.

here are a few common errors I see:

> `"The name ViewData does not exist in the current context"`
>   `"The name TempData does not exist in the current context"`
>   `"The name Model does not exist in the current context"`

For example, my RazorPage called `Contact-Us.cshtml` (with the hyphen) will error

[image: no]

Whereas, my page `ContactUs.cshtml` (without the hyphen) will be fine.

[image: yes]

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: I dont know if it is a bug or a constraint imposed by the design. Each razor page can have a code-behind file with the name `Contact-Us.cshtml.cs` and the class would be `Contact-Us`. That doesnt seem like a valid class name. Maybe the error message could be improved, but it sounds like something the design just doesnt allow for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue reported on GitHub. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6296

> This is a known bug and will be resolved with the release of **Visual Studio 15.5**